# javascript: Loop Function on Array With Holes

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

If I create a sparse `array` (which has some holes in it), the array functions, like `.map()`, `.reduce()`, `.forEach()` will skip these holes.

```
[, , 1, , 2].forEach((item) => console.log(item)) 
// 1
// 2
```

what I'm looking for is an array function which does not skip the holes, and works like this:

```
[, , 1, , 2].fullForEach((item) => console.log(item))
// undefined
// undefined
// 1
// undefined
// 2
```

I would like to loop on the original array, and NOT to convert the holes in the array to actual `undefined` values, i.e. none of the following is what I'm looking for:

```
Array.from([, , 1, , 2]).forEach();
[...[, , 1, , 2]].forEach();
```

I'm looking for a **functional** solution for this, which means I'd like to get a solution without any `for` / `while` loop.

Comment: why is the downvote?

Comment: The term you're looking for is dealing with "sparse" arrays, and why is `Array.from` not acceptable?

Comment: @Emissary, because that converts the array holes to actual values which I'd like to avoid.

Comment: map, reduce and forEach all use for/while loops inside. Since they ignore empty array elements, you might need to write your own function which uses a for/while loop. Look the polyfill for map: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: @Danmoreng, I didn't know they're using for/while loops. Where can I read more about how they work inside?

Comment: @Adam I just edited the mozilla reference in my last comment afterwards :D

Comment: As Danmoreng pointed out, you'll have to do this yourself, an example is available here https://jsfiddle.net/dbk3qonh/

Comment: @Liam MacDonald , what I'm curious about is if there is solution without the  use of a `for` loop.

Comment: Why is that an issue, out of interest? The only way to iterate over an array is with a loop, whether you write the loop or use an existing function a loop will still happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will work.

```
[,,1,4,,,,1].find((item) => console.log(item));
```

Comment: Thank you! It's great to know that `find` iterates on indexes, and not on elements:) I'm still wondering why does this work differently then other array functions :-/

Comment: `Array.prototype.find` is not appropriate for this. Please see my answer for additional explanation.

Comment: "You should not be using Array.prototype.find for this – find will stop iterating as soon as a truthy value is returned " - just not return true if you not want to exit :) this what i meant. (Which not makes find usage correct, but makes it behave same as forEach

Comment: However it adds a possibility like imterrptable reduce (not very practical imho)

Answer (score 4):

You should not be using `Array.prototype.find` for this – `find` will stop iterating as soon as a truthy value is returned from the function. It's only continuing to iterate in the `console.log` example provided because `console.log` is a side-effecting function and always returns `undefined`, a non-truthy value.

Instead, you should make your own iterator that properly describes the behavior you actually intend. As others commented, there is nothing wrong with using a `for` or `while` loop – that's exactly how the native functionals like `reduce` and `map` are implemented anyway. What you're looking for is the creation of a functional *interface* – ie, it doesn't matter what your function looks like on the inside; the user of your function gets to work with it in a purely functional way.

```js
Array.prototype.fullForEach = function (f, env) {
  for (let i = 0; i < this.length; i++)
    f.call(env, this[i], i, this)
}

Array.prototype.fullReduce = function (f, acc, env) {
  for (let i = 0; i < this.length; i++)
    acc = f.call(env, acc, this[i], i, this)
  return acc
}
    
Array.prototype.fullMap = function (f, env) {
  return this.fullReduce((acc, x, i) => [...acc, f.call(env, x, i, this)], [], env)
}

const arr = [,,,2,,]

arr.fullForEach((x, i, xs) => console.log(x, i, xs))
// undefined 0 [ , , , 2,  ]
// undefined 1 [ , , , 2,  ]
// undefined 2 [ , , , 2,  ]
// 2 3 [ , , , 2,  ]
// undefined 4 [ , , , 2,  ]

console.log(arr.fullMap(x => x ? x : 'void'))
// [ 'void', 'void', 'void', 2, 'void' ]

console.log(arr.fullMap(function (x) { return x ? x : this.default }, { default: 'void' }))
// [ 'void', 'void', 'void', 2, 'void' ]

console.log(arr.fullReduce((acc, x) => x ? acc + x : acc + '-', ''))
// ---2-

console.log(arr.fullReduce(function (acc, x) { return x ? acc + x : acc + this.default }, '', { default: '-' }))
// ---2-
```

You can continue implementing the other useful functionals `filter`, `every`, `some`, etc.

I took care to ensure these behave like `forEach`, `map`, and `reduce` counterparts; specifically with regard to the ability to change the lambda's context – note, changing context only works with non-arrow functions, as demoed in the code

So what did we learn? We implemented functional interfaces for `fullForEach`, `fullReduce`, and `fullMap` using simple `for` loops. However, when the function is called, the user is not burdened with these details and is allowed to express their program in a functional style.

Comment: Who stop you to return always false from your processor ? :)

Comment: @zb' i don't understand what you are asking